# Signing a card or letter using "famiglia"

Tags: articles, formal, greeting, letter-writing

When signing a card or letter, is it "Famiglia & Surname" or "La famiglia & Surname"?

Maybe my question was not clear enough.

My question is which form is correct:

1. Famiglia Niccoli             or
2. La Famiglia Niccoli

Thank you.

Comment: Famiglia, without "la".

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica, the surname is the family name...

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica, what do you mean by “yes and no”? “Surname” means “family name”, and the OP asked about the use of surnames (not first names) in conjunction with the Italian word _famiglia_.

Comment: +1 for having updated the question, now it is way more clear (and interesting). And I am not sure that the article should be avoided: without it, sounds strange to me.

Answer (score 9):

If you mean a literal “&”, none of the proposed forms is meaningful. In an informal communication, you'd use the first name followed, if necessary, by *e famiglia*. For instance:

> (Saluti da) Mario e famiglia.

In a formal context, you might use *famiglia* followed by the family name:

> (Sentite condoglianze), famiglia Rossi.

Comment: Your answers are greatfully appreciated.